# VBS: find max str length in 2D array (rows and columns)

Tags: vbscript

1. Need to find max string length in 2D array (rows and columns) to calculate minimum column width.
2. How to define fixed array size based on variable values (it can be returned from tool)?

```
'So now here we have:

Dim arr()
Dim nRowsMax, nColumnMax
nRows = oTool.MaxRowCount
nColumns = oTool.MaxColCount

ReDim arr(nRows, nColumns)

Dim sCellValue : sCellValue = oTool.Value(nRow, nCol)
Dim nCellWidth = Len(sCellValue)

Dim nRow, nCol
For nRow = 1 To nRows
    For nColumn = 1 To nColumns
        If arr(nRow, nCol) < nMin Then nMin = arr(nRow, nCol)
        If arr(nRow, nCol) > nMax Then nMax = arr(nRow, nCol)
    Next ' Column
Next ' Row
```

Comment: It's probably going to have to be done the tedious way - 2 for loops with a test in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated question and comments, here's an adjusted answer:

```
Dim iRows, iColumns
Dim iRowCounter, iColumnCounter
Dim sValue
Dim iLength
Dim iMaxLength
Dim arrMaxLength()

iRows = oTool.MaxRowCount
iColumns = oTool.MaxColCount

' Set array dimensions based on values from oTool
ReDim arrMaxLength(iColumns)

For iColumnCounter = 1 To iColumns

    arrMaxLength(iColumnCounter - 1) = 0

    For iRowCounter = 1 To iRows

        ' Get value and compare negth with previous iMaxLength
        sValue = oTool.Value(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter)
        iLength = Len(sValue)
        If iLength > iMaxLength Then iMaxLength = iLength
        If iLength > arrMaxLength(iColumnCounter - 1) Then arrMaxLength(iColumnCounter - 1) = iLength

    Next ' Row

Next ' Column
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that: sCellValue = oTool.Value(nRow, nCol) and nCellWidth = Len(sCellValue).

Comment: So you can simply call `sValue = oTool.Value(iRowCounter  - 1, iColumnCounter - 1)` directly then, you don't even need the `arr` array.

Comment: So I can calculate column width and list all table items at once?

Comment: One thing that I missed. In example of your code there is a max calculated from whole 2D table. What I need to get is to calculate each column width based on table items so it needs to be calculated per column and then all items listed.

Comment: Updated answer with code to track max column lengths. `iMaxLength` is the largest overall while `arrMaxLength(column)` (zero-based array) contains max lengths of each column.